# mysql update insert join avoid duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a table that I wish to update (or insert if no previous condition exists)

```
servers table              clusters table              datacenters table  

server_id | server_name     cluster_id | cluster_name   datacenter_id | datacenter_name
-----------------------     -------------------------   -------------------------------
1           server1          1           cluster1        1               datacentereast
2           server7          3           Cluster22       5               datacenterwest


server_status table

status_id   |    status_server   | status_cluster | status_datacenter
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I wish to populate server_status with the ids of the other tables and avoid duplicates.

So far I have :

```
sql_string = """  
INSERT into server_status (status_datacenter,status_cluster, status_server)
    SELECT 
        d.datacenter_id,c.cluster_id,s.server_id 
    FROM 
        datacenters as d, clusters as c, servers as s
    WHERE
        d.datacenter_name = \'%s\' 
        AND c.cluster_name = \'%s\'
        AND s.server_name = \'%s\'
        AND d.datacenter_id != status_datacenter
        AND c.cluster_id != status_cluster
        AND s.server_id != status_server;
    """ % (datacenter,cluster,server)
```

The above fails with:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'status_datacenter' in 'where clause'")
```

Print out of an actual sql command:

```
INSERT into server_status (status_datacenter,status_cluster, status_server) 
 SELECT d.datacenter_id,c.cluster_id,s.server_id 
  FROM datacenters as d, clusters as c, servers as s 
   WHERE d.datacenter_name = 'SDDC' 
   AND c.cluster_name = 'qboc37' 
   AND s.server_name = 'ap30' 
   AND d.datacenter_id != status_datacenter 
   AND c.cluster_id != status_cluster 
   AND s.server_id != status_server;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a unique index on `server_status (status_datacenter,status_cluster, status_server)`, then

```
INSERT IGNORE into server_status (status_datacenter,status_cluster, status_server) 
 SELECT d.datacenter_id,c.cluster_id,s.server_id 
  FROM datacenters as d, clusters as c, servers as s 
   WHERE d.datacenter_name = 'SDDC' 
   AND c.cluster_name = 'qboc37' 
   AND s.server_name = 'ap30'
```